# Android: conflict between rotate & limit zooming of imageview

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, zooming

My program run well when rotate & unlimit zooming or only limit zooming without rotating.
Here is a part of my code:

```
} else if (mode == ZOOM) {
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            if (newDist > 10f) {
                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                matrix.getValues(mValues1);
                float currentScale = mValues1[0];
                if (currentScale * scale < MIN_ZOOM) {
                    scale = MIN_ZOOM / currentScale;
                } else if (currentScale * scale > MAX_ZOOM) {
                    scale = MAX_ZOOM / currentScale;
                }
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                matrix.getValues(mValues1);
                Log.e("ZOOM", "scale " + mValues1[0]);
            }

            /*
             * uncomment to enable rotating
             * this function conflicts with zooming limitation
             */
            if (lastEvent != null) {
                newRot = rotation(event);
                float r = newRot - d;
                matrix.postRotate(r, mid.x, mid.y);
                matrix.getValues(mValues1);
                Log.e("ROTATE", " scale " + mValues1[0]);
            }
        }
```

As I think something wrong is after maxtrix.postRotate executed, mValues1[0] - scale value be changed, and in next looping, currentScale will also be changed, so limit zoom checking become wrong. 
Give me some ideas. Thank for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the bug by other way. I not using matrix value for currentScale:

```
float currentScale = mValues1[0];
```

I use other global variable "previsousScale" like below:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        // second finger lifted
        mode = NONE;
        lastEvent = null;
        previousScale *= tempScale;
        if (previousScale > MAX_ZOOM)
            previousScale = MAX_ZOOM;
        else if (previousScale < MIN_ZOOM)
            previousScale = MIN_ZOOM;
        break;
```

and in case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

```
} else if (mode == ZOOM) {
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            if (newDist > 10f) {
                tempScale = newDist / oldDist;
                if (previousScale * tempScale < MIN_ZOOM) {
                    tempScale = MIN_ZOOM / previousScale;
                } else if (previousScale * tempScale > MAX_ZOOM) {
                    tempScale = MAX_ZOOM / previousScale;
                }
                matrix.postScale(tempScale, tempScale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }

            if (lastEvent != null) {
                 newRot = rotation(event);
                 float r = newRot - d;
                 matrix.postRotate(r, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
        }
```